# Suppose $A=\bigcup_i A_i$ is f-invariant. Then $f^n(A_i)\subseteq A$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, invariance

Suppose $A=\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i, A_i\subseteq X,$ for some index set $I$ and $A$ is $f$-invariant for some function $f\colon X\to X$,

Does this imply that, for each $i\in I$,
$$
f^n(A_i)\subseteq A~\forall n\in\mathbb{N}?
$$

My answer is *yes*:

$A$ f-invariant means 
$$
f(A)=\bigcup_{i\in I}f(A_i)\subseteq A.
$$

Moreover, $A_i\subseteq A$.

Both together should give
$$
f^n(A_i)\subseteq f^n(A)=f^{n-1}(f(A))\subseteq f^{n-1}(A)=f^{n-2}(f(A))\subseteq f^{n-2}(A)
$$

and repeating this again and again, I get
$$
f^n(A_i)\subseteq f(A)\subseteq A.
$$

Am I right?

Comment: I think you are right.

Comment: That's right. To shape it into a formal proof, you replace the 'repeating this again and again [...]' part by an induction on $n$.